# How do I make VSCode show errors only for opened files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing small programs, consisting of 1 source file, but when I open 1 of them, it automatically scans other files and shows errors, is there a way to disable that?

Comment: That depends on the language extension that you're using.

Comment: I'm using golang